# TAG: bestpractice

Tags: discussion, tags, interesting-tags

The [bestpractice](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bestpractice) - I think it should not be used.

A question that is tagged with it, immediately calls for a discussion. I think if the question is asked correctly, this tag should not be used.

Ofc, we can control the answers and comments, and block spammage etc..

There are currently [8 questions tagged](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bestpractice), and I think that they can all be retagged. Once the question is posted, everyone will answer their own views anyway.

thoughts?

Comment: I'd not spotted it yet, but I'm inclined to agree with you.

Comment: @LaceySnr :-)  you closed the most obvious one, but all other questions have the same symptoms of opening a disucssion

Comment: Agreed - `bestpractice` invites a discussion.

Comment: agree! This tag is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I disagree that the tag calls for a discussion. "Best practice" does not mean "What I like to do" it means "The official, recommended way" to do something. Maybe my definition is not held by everyone, however.

Often a question has a number of possible solutions, some being a bit more "hack-ish" than others. If asking for a best pratice, to me that means you are asking for the officially sanctioned, Marc Benioff blessed way of doing something - which actually should have a very specific answer (if it has one at all).

Now, whether we need a tag for that or not is a different topic. From that angle it's not really a big deal to me one way or the other. It would probably be more appropriate to be able to tag an answer as "best practice" (using my definition) than the question - because the "best practice" answer may or may not be the best solution to the problem.

Comment: Well, it's SE, once you ask a question, you are bound to get 1 to several ways of doing, achieving your goal. The voting system is the one that tells you on the way that most think is the correct/best practice. Once you tag a question like that, I feel, it asks for a discussion. JMP

Answer (score 0):

"this development platform will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Salesforce is weird. On the plus side, it's an easy language with good documentation. The simple Q&As are already answered . . . except for those simple Questions whose answer is "you can't" and from that point forward, you're kind of stuck having a discussion. What this community needs is a place to have these discussions, free from the problems of potentially embarrassing our employers or irritating our CSMs. I'm not saying the policy is fundamentally bad, I'm just saying dial it back for salesforce.

Comment: I can offer to have a special chat room for that - it can be a nice backbone adition

Comment: Being an SE newbie, I originally thought something similar to you, but I found that many "Best Practice" questions can be better worded as SE appropriate questions to solicit more exact answers which is more beneficial IMO anyway. The questions that can't be really are not appropriate for SE.  Like @Saariko said, there's always chat.